# robot's urdf and robot pose ekf

Tags: navigation, urdf, transform, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a problem. I wrote an urdf file for my robot tried it on RVIZ an it worked well.
now I want to combine it with robot_pose_ekf package after I wrote an appropriate launch file I have got a problem because my main transform is the first link of the robot and not the odom_combined transform. when I am trying to change that there is a mess in connections between the links and odom_combined transforms, or even there is no connection at all.

what could be the problem?

please help...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54401/robot%27s-urdf-and-robot-pose-ekf/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem comes from the fact that robot_pose_ekf creates a transform between your main transform and /odom_combined. But since your main transform has already a parent (as far as I understand) and transforms cannot have multiple parents, it creates a mess.

It would surely help to see the tf tree to find out the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Akin](https://answers.ros.org/users/230/akin/) with karma: 186 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0